# Explode 2 columns into multiple columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark dataframe:

```
+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|id                              |order  |cart                                |item       |sub               |rank              |   
+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|694e45100f52475d8dac13b829e02394|null   |baa4b664-8a84-4abb-8919-01836340a30a|826017462  |697030209         |6                 |
|532f20768ce64599b6f79bb17b9fc597|null   |aa45d078-dfc6-4710-adac-4385b43d3eba|10402650   |13893731          |3                 |
|fae01765055f4df0a1041de0669393e6|null   |f7b498d6-ea9c-47e7-9220-ec18070f9ee8|293214825  |1226495201        |4                 |
|f2135f7919713625e044001517f43a86|null   |d4873f7a-2219-49d9-a0e8-cb41d24f8aec|814735847  |222288904         |2                 |
|6e74f194b9d2403cb6d28f0a33a00a9a|null   |20753b35-36bd-4679-9d64-c480c9c19b97|10291833   |10313028          |1                 |
+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

And I would like to explode the columns into multiple columns based on columns sub and rank.

```
+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|id                              |order  |cart                                |item       |sub               |rank              | sub1        | sub2        | sub3        | sub4        | sub5        | sub6        | sub7        |
+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+ 
|694e45100f52475d8dac13b829e02394|null   |baa4b664-8a84-4abb-8919-01836340a30a|826017462  |697030209         |6                 |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |697030209    |  0          |      
|532f20768ce64599b6f79bb17b9fc597|null   |aa45d078-dfc6-4710-adac-4385b43d3eba|10402650   |13893731          |3                 |  0          |  0          |13893731     |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |      
|fae01765055f4df0a1041de0669393e6|null   |f7b498d6-ea9c-47e7-9220-ec18070f9ee8|293214825  |1226495201        |4                 |  0          |  0          |  0          | 1226495201  |  0          |  0          |  0          |      
|f2135f7919713625e044001517f43a86|null   |d4873f7a-2219-49d9-a0e8-cb41d24f8aec|814735847  |222288904         |2                 |  0          | 222288904   |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |      
|6e74f194b9d2403cb6d28f0a33a00a9a|null   |20753b35-36bd-4679-9d64-c480c9c19b97|10291833   |10313028          |1                 |  10313028   |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |  0          |      
+--------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get this ?

Comment: Can you explain what logic should be used to achieve this? For example how sub 13893731 transformed from rank 6 to rank 3?

Comment: How the column rans is constructed in the result dataframe ?

Comment: Sorry Guys, i have corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the max value of the rank column, and create the sub_i columns using a loop, I don't think is possible to do it with a pivot, here's a pseudocode:

```
max_rank = df.agg(max("rank")).collect()[0][0]
for i in range(1, int(max_rank) + 2):
    df = df.withColumn(f"sub{i}", when(col("rank") == i, col("sub")).otherwise(lit(0)))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------+---------+----------+----+----+--------+---------+--------+----------+----+---------+----+
|id                              |order|cart                                |item     |sub       |rank|sub0|sub1    |sub2     |sub3    |sub4      |sub5|sub6     |sub7|
+--------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------+---------+----------+----+----+--------+---------+--------+----------+----+---------+----+
|694e45100f52475d8dac13b829e02394|null |baa4b664-8a84-4abb-8919-01836340a30a|826017462|697030209 |6   |0   |0       |0        |0       |0         |0   |697030209|0   |
|532f20768ce64599b6f79bb17b9fc597|null |aa45d078-dfc6-4710-adac-4385b43d3eba|10402650 |13893731  |3   |0   |0       |0        |13893731|0         |0   |0        |0   |
|fae01765055f4df0a1041de0669393e6|null |f7b498d6-ea9c-47e7-9220-ec18070f9ee8|293214825|1226495201|4   |0   |0       |0        |0       |1226495201|0   |0        |0   |
|f2135f7919713625e044001517f43a86|null |d4873f7a-2219-49d9-a0e8-cb41d24f8aec|814735847|222288904 |2   |0   |0       |222288904|0       |0         |0   |0        |0   |
|6e74f194b9d2403cb6d28f0a33a00a9a|null |20753b35-36bd-4679-9d64-c480c9c19b97|10291833 |10313028  |1   |0   |10313028|0        |0       |0         |0   |0        |0   |
+--------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------+---------+----------+----+----+--------+---------+--------+----------+----+---------+----+
```